# How to stop Observable.fromiterable and restart iteration with new list?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, imagedownload, rx-kotlin

I am having a list of images which i wanted to download.So below is the code which i used:

```
Observable.fromIterable(imagelist).subscribeOn(Scheduler.io). subscribe {
//download logic
}.addtodisposible(compositedisposible)
```

Initially, all downloaded images are saved into folder A.
Now I have written a condition inside this iteration. if that condition satisfies, it should break the loop and call the same function again with only remaining items that are left to be iterated/downloaded and store it in folder B.
Note:-1-> I tried to use takeuntil and added a Boolean value which i turn true if that condition satisfies.but iteration doesn't stop.
2-> if i clear composite disposible, the iteration stops and iteration with new items also begins, but iterates only few items.

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the requirement: call with remaining items <- that's just continuing the loop.

Comment: Sorry , my mistake. I forgot to mention. I download the images into a folder A. After condition satifies , it should break the loop and  the remaining images should be downloaded into folder B.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a phase change in your `subscribe`'s `onNext` call since you have to process the full `imagelist` either way. Just have an external variable that remembers which phase are you in and do an `if` in the `onNext` call:

```java
var phase = AtomicBoolean();

Observable.fromIterable(imagelist)
.subscribeOn(Scheduler.io)
.subscribe {
    if (!phase.get()) {
        // download to folder A
        // process the image here
        // then make a decision if it is time to switch
        if (someCondition) {
            phase.set(true)
        }
    } else {
        // download to folder B
    }
}.addtodisposible(compositedisposible)
```

Comment: I will try implementing the same. Thanks for the reply. Really appreciate it. I have been stuck on this issue for past how many days i don't remember.